# How to create a new id of a dom in jQuery when cloning that dom element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Actually I want to create an unique id for every DOM element which is cloning when the DOM element is dropped in a container and show it in a text area. That text area will show every DOM element's unique id in a list which is dropped in the container. Answer should be in jQuery.

Can any one there to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just spin through the elements (using jQuery, or just a boring old recursive descent function using the DOM) and set their `id` property to something unique.

To set the `id` of an element using the DOM:

```
element_reference.id = newId;
```

With jQuery (1.6 and higher):

```
jquery_instance.prop("id", newId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<=10;i++)
  $('#clonedSource').clone().attr('id', 'newElementId'+i).appendTo('#container');
```